# Require JS - Loads all javascript files with pressing Ctrl + F5

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

Am using require Js in my project. Everything seems to be working fine. No JS conflicts nothing.

But, when I press CTRL + F5 to clear reload the page in Firefox, I observe 55 Javascript files are getting loaded , refering to NET tab in Firebug.

Is this normal?, Am I doing anything wrong?

This is my BOOT.js

```
require
        .config({

            baseUrl : 'resources/js',
            paths : {
                domReady : 'lib/domReady',
                jquery : 'lib/jquery.min',
                jqueryUI : 'lib/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min',
                date : 'lib/date',
                tmpl : 'lib/jquery.tmpl.min',
                underscore : 'lib/underscore-min',
                backbone : 'lib/backbone',
                handlebars : 'lib/handlebars-v1.1.2',
                socket : 'lib/knotifyjs',
                eve : 'lib/eve',
                raphael : 'lib/raphael-min',
                chronoline : 'lib/chronoline',
                fullcalendar : 'lib/fullcalendar',
                timeago : 'lib/jquery.timeago',
                openStreet : 'lib/openstreet/OpenLayers',
                timeago : 'lib/jquery.timeago',
                foundation : 'lib/foundation.min',
                fDropdown : 'lib/foundation.dropdown',
                fTopBar : 'lib/foundation.topbar',
                jgrowl : 'lib/jquery.jgrowl.min',
                jQgrid : 'lib/jqgrid',
                jQgridLocale : 'lib/jgrid-locale',
                jqueryForm : 'lib/jquery.form',
                validateForm : 'lib/validate',
                jsPlumb : 'lib/jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all',
                carousel : 'lib/carousel.min',
                spin : 'lib/spin',
                datePicker : 'lib/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon',
                timeSlider : 'lib/jquery-ui-slider-access',
                maps : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false',
                autoCompleteMap : "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places",
                weather : 'lib/jquery.zweatherfeed.min',
                picker : 'lib/picker',
                jsonQLang : 'lib/JSLINQ',
                pickerTime : 'lib/picker.time',
                jqueryFlot : 'lib/jquery.flot',
                jFlotCategory : 'lib/jquery.flot.categories',
                jFlotTime : 'lib/jquery.flot.time',
                jFlotAxisLabel : 'lib/jqflot-axislabels',
                "moment" : "lib/moment.min",
                "moment-timezone" : "lib/moment-timezone.min",
                "moment-timezone-data" : "lib/timezone-data",
                jScrollPane : 'lib/jquery.jscrollpane.min',
                app : 'app'
            },

            waitSeconds : 300,
            shim : {

                "jqueryUI" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : "jqueryUI"
                },

                "datePicker" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery', 'jqueryUI' ],
                    exports : 'datePicker'
                },

                "timeSlider" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'timeSlider'
                },

                "jqueryForm" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : "jqueryForm"
                },
                "jsonQLang" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : "jsonQLang"

                },

                "picker" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'picker'
                },
                "pickerTime" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'pickerTime'
                },

                "backbone" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery', 'underscore' ],
                    exports : 'Backbone'
                },
                "handlebars" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone' ],
                    exports : 'Handlebars'
                },

                "tmpl" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'tmpl'
                },

                'eve' : {
                    exports : "eve"
                },

                'raphael' : {
                    deps : [ "eve" ],
                    exports : "Raphael"
                },

                "fullcalendar" : {
                    deps : [ "jquery" ],
                    exports : "fullcalendar"
                },

                "map" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : "maps"
                },
                "autoCompleteMap" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : "autoCompleteMap"
                },
                "jqueryFlot" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : "jqueryFlot"
                },
                "jFlotCategory" : {
                    deps : [ 'jqueryFlot' ],
                    exports : "jFlotCategory"
                },

                "jFlotAxisLabel" : {
                    deps : [ 'jqueryFlot' ],
                    exports : "jFlotAxisLabel"
                },
                "jFlotTime" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : "jFlotTime"
                },
                "foundation" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'foundation'
                },

                "timePicker" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'timePicker'
                },

                "fTopBar" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery', 'foundation' ],
                    exports : 'fDropdown'
                },

                "fDropdown" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery', 'foundation' ],
                    exports : 'fTopBar'
                },
                "validateForm" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : "validateForm"
                },

                "jQgridLocale" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'jQgridLocale'
                },

                "jQgrid" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery', 'jQgridLocale' ],
                    exports : 'jQgrid'
                },

                "jsPlumb" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'jsPlumb'
                },

                "openStreet" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'openStreet'
                },

                "jgrowl" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'jgrowl'
                },

                "weather" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'weather'
                },

                "carousel" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : 'carousel'
                },

                "spin" : {
                    exports : 'spin'
                },

                "jScrollPane" : {
                    deps : [ 'jquery' ],
                    exports : "jScrollPane"
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it be right? While you are on development mode, RequireJS will asynchronously load all your files as your code requires them. Once you are ready to go to production mode, you should use [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to optimize your build and generate a single JS file to be served to the browser.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. So now I used r.js to get one sing file main.js of size 1.4MB
Now I changed the require js include with "data-main" attribute.
Should I still see the JS files getting loaded in NET tab?? or I should see only one single file getting loaded??

Comment: After using r.js the browser should only load a single file with all your code an libraries.

Comment: Not it has built one single JS file of size 1.8 MB. I changed the include of require js with data-main attribute. But still I see a list of files getting loaded instead of one single file in "NET" tab